# Akka-http: How to get custom header from a request?

Tags: akka, spray, akka-http

I send following headers in a request to my akka-http api: `"Content-type": "application/json"`, `"Accept": "application/json"`, `"AppId": "some_id"`.

How do I get "AppId" custom header in my akka-http route?

```
(get & parameters("id")) { (id) =>
      complete {
        val appId = ?? // I want to get custom header here.
      }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use one of the `HeaderDirectives` ([HeaderDirectives docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/header-directives/index.html#headerdirectives)) to extract the header. For example, if it's a custom one you can use [headerValueByName](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/header-directives/headerValueByName.html) which yields the value of the header, and rejects the route if the header was not present (if the header is optional you can use `optionalHeaderValueByName`):

```scala
headerValueByName("AppId") { appId =>
  complete(s"The AppId was: $appId")
}
```

Happy hakking!

Comment: What if I need to extract multiple custom headers? I have to nest multiple HeaderDirectives? Code would get quite messy if I have many of custom headers.

Comment: That's why it's possible to write custom directives, so you can have a directive that pulls everything you need together and call it `allMyCustomHeaders { headers => }` for example. I'm porting these docs currently to Akka HTTP, so you'll have to read them from the spray documentation for now: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/advanced-topics/custom-directives/ It's all the same from the user's perspective here though :)

Answer (score 6):

I actually prefer creating custom directive for things like authentication tokens, app ids and other parameters that are sort of mandatory for serving client's request. In your case it might look like this

```
val extractAppId = (headerValueByName("AppId") | headerValueByName("AppId2")).tflatMap[Tuple1[String]] {
  case Tuple1(appId) =>
    if (!appId.equalsIgnoreCase("BannedAppId"))
      provide(appId)
    else
      complete(StatusCodes.Forbidden -> "Your application is banned")
}.recover {
  case rejections => reject(ValidationRejection("AppId is not provided"))
}
```

which is used like

```
extractAppId { appId =>
 get {
  complete {
   "Your AppId is " + appId
  }
 }
}
```

To make my example more interesting I added support of conditional response based on provided AppId.

Comment: Could you please provide me with the example how to get multiple headers in one directive? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. You need to use `|` (OR) operator. I updated the answer.

Comment: Or you need to you `&` to get tuple of several values.