# Can akka HttpHeader store an X-Request-ID or X-Correlation-ID Field?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to store/lookup an [X-Request-ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_fields) in an akka [`HttpRequest`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpRequest.html) but [`HttpHeader`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpHeader.html) doesn't appear to have an appropriate subclass.

**Is it possible to access the X-Request-ID field, or X-Correlation-ID field, in an HttpHeader?**

According to the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/http-model.html#header-model) the following code gets the Authorization token:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers._

case class User(name: String, pass: String)

// a method that extracts basic HTTP credentials from a request
def credentialsOfRequest(req: HttpRequest): Option[User] =
  for {
    Authorization(BasicHttpCredentials(user, pass)) <- req.header[Authorization]
  } yield User(user, pass)
```

But the `headers` package doesn't have a corresponding case class for X-Request-ID.  There are `X-Forward-For` and `X-Real-Ip` which are also ["Common non-standard request fields"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_response_fields).

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618052/akka-http-how-to-get-custom-header-from-a-request) concerning "custom headers" but I was hoping to not have to go that route...

Is there any alternative to using custom headers?

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a [Custom Header](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/http-model.html#custom-headers) to get the functionality you desire, as shown below:

```
def requestIdOfRequest(req: HttpRequest): Option[String] =
  for {
    `X-Request-Id`(id) <- req.header[`X-Request-Id`]
  } yield id

final class `X-Request-Id`(id: String) extends ModeledCustomHeader[`X-Request-Id`] {
  override def renderInRequests = false
  override def renderInResponses = false
  override val companion = `X-Request-Id`
  override def value: String = id
}

object `X-Request-Id` extends ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion[`X-Request-Id`] {
  override val name = "X-Request-Id"
  override def parse(value: String) = Try(new `X-Request-Id`(value))
}
```

Scaladoc: [ModeledCustomHeader](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/headers/ModeledCustomHeader.html), [ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/headers/ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I guess custom header is the only route.  I'm going to submit a ticket to get the rest of the non-standand request fields.

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil Better yet, you could submit a [pull request](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/pulls) :) .  It sounds like these are something you are going to be implementing for your project anyway it wouldn't be much additional work to implement them in akka-http instead of in your project. (I went digging in akka-http source when preparing the answer above).